# Как вытащить значение после символа # в адресной строке?

Tags: php

сайт.ру/#**get**

Собственно нужно вытащить значение **get** средствами PHP. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, получаем через javascript

```
function get_piece_url() {
   return var purl=location.search.substring(1);
}
```

И вот этот полученный кусок адреса отправляем на сервер для обработки средствами php.

Answer (score 2):

Не вытащить его срадствами php.. скипед сервак все что после #

Была такая же проблема.. решил с помощью js. Им туда добраться можно..

Comment: Вариант с JS уже рассмотрен. Подожду грандиозных идей еще)

Comment: С радостью подожду грандиозного решения ) Самому интересно.. :)

Comment: > Подожду грандиозных идей еще)

Ждать долго придется. Имхо, браузеры начнут передавать на сервер hashmark'и не раньше, чем *никогда* :)

Comment: Спасибо, уже JS впарил!)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = parse_url("сайт.ру/#get");
$fragment = $url['fragment'];//тут и будет Ваш get
```

[Manual: parse_url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Как парсить я в курсе, мне нужно для начала передать адресную строку в `$url`, а потом уже парсить сам `$url`!

Comment: Тогда единственный  способ использовать его в PHP - это делать ajax-запрос из js и включать значение хэша как какую-нибудь обычную переменную в запросе.
через <code>window.location.hash</code>